# Yeoman prompt: how generate a valid filename from a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filenames, yeoman

Is there a method implemented in Yeoman or in Node to generate a valid filename from a string?

My aim is to replace accented letters by normal letters, spaces by dashes, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, all you need is a function that removes special characters and perhaps replaces them using an arbitrary system.

One option was already named by passy, which is to make use of:

```
this._.dasherize(str)
```

Nevertheless, there are some additional options you might use. E.g., you might check out the [underscore.string module](http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/), which provides some functions for this. From these, I'd highly recommend the `slugify` function:

From the [documentation](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme):

> Transform text into a URL slug. Replaces whitespaces, accentuated, and special characters with a dash.

To provide an example:

```
_.slugify("Un éléphant à l'orée du bois")
=> 'un-elephant-a-loree-du-bois';
```

This should be exactly what you need, and still keeps a good readability.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For Yeoman generators, the common way to handle this is to use `this._.dasherize(str)` in the JavaScript generator code or `<%= _.dasherize(str) %>` in templates. It doesn't take care of accented letters, but those should be valid filenames anyway.

```
console.log(this._.dasherize("some userProvided string")); 
// output: "some-user-provided-string"
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for that (useful, but not complete)

Comment: I agree, Golo's answer is much better. :)