# How to make a valid filename from an arbitrary string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, compatibility

Is there a way to convert an arbitrary string to a valid filename in Javascript?

The result should stick as close to the original string as possible, to be easy for humans to read (therefore [slugify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083580/yeoman-prompt-how-generate-a-valid-filename-from-a-string) is not an option). This means it needs only to replace characters which [are not supported by an OS](http://xahlee.info/mswin/allowed_chars_in_file_names.html).

For example:

```
'Article: "Un éléphant à l\'orée du bois/An elephant at the edge of the woods".txt'
→ 'Article   Un éléphant à l\'orée du bois An elephant at the edge of the woods .txt'
```

I thought that this would be a common problem, but I haven't found any solutions to it. I hope you can help me!

Comment: first you'd have to know what the target OS is - there's no point in sanitizing for Windows, if it the file's going onto a Mac, and vice versa... Otherwise, you'd have to just go with the least common denominator `a-z0-9\-`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot target an OS. I am saving files (with the generated filenames) to Dropbox, so I can access them from wherever I want.

But according to [this](http://xahlee.info/mswin/allowed_chars_in_file_names.html), it shouldn't be a problem. I'll just target Windows and it will work also on Mac. (I guess this is what you meant by "least common denominator")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to [Kelvin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35511533/3763660) answer!

I quickly compiled it into a function. The final code I used is:

```
function convertToValidFilename(string) {
    return (string.replace(/[\/|\\:*?"<>]/g, " "));
}

var string = 'Un éléphant à l\'orée du bois/An elephant at the edge of the woods".txt';

console.log("Before = ", string);
console.log("After  = ", convertToValidFilename(string));
```

This results in the output:

```
Before =  Un éléphant à l'orée du bois/An elephant at the edge of the woods".txt
After  =  Un éléphant à l orée du bois An elephant at the edge of the woods .txt
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use string replace function

```js
var str = 'Article: "Un éléphant à l'orée du bois/An elephant at the edge of the woods".txt';
var out = (str.replace(/[ &\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, ""));
```

#### Or expect number and letter

```js
var out=(str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to the variable, you use a single quote ', in which the string will break if you have another ' in your string. You need to add a backslash \ before the single quote inside when you declare the string.

However, if the string you are using is got from somewhere, then you don't need to add a backslash because it's probably handled well in another place.

Note that / \ : * ? " < > | are not allowed for filename.

So if the value is set in a variable already, you need to remove all these characters. Do this

```
    var str = 'Article: "Un éléphant à l\'orée du bois/An elephant at the edge of the woods".txt';
    str = str.replace(/[\/\\:*?"<>]/g, ""));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing backslash (it was meant as pseudocode, but I now added it for clarity).

Comment: I took your solution and wrote a short code snippet with a function, so other people can just copy paste it for their projects. Thank you very much for the quick reply! This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: I also added "|" to the string replacement, as it seems you forgot to add it (even though you mentioned it in your text)